# Make a bot respond to reactions to a specific message - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I started reworking my mod-mail bot and wanted to give the user a choice on what server they want to contact. Since there are 2 server the bot reactions with 2 reactions and based on what the users reacts to, it contacts that server.

But I ran into a problem. When trying to do this. I couldn't find a way to have like an if else function, where if the users reacts to one of the reactions added, it contacts that server.

How can I make it so where if the user reactions to the green reaction the bot does something else than if the user reacted to the red reaction.

Here is my code:

```
def green_check(reaction, user):
        return str(reaction.emoji) == '' and user != bot.user

    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=3600.0, check=green_check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await concept_msg.delete()
        await ctx.author.send("No moderator responded, wait some time and try again.")
        return
    else:
        concept_embed_dict = concept_embed.to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your check you can see if the emoji is either one of the two things you want, and then later check which one it is and execute the code that you want.
Something like this maybe?

```py
def green_check(reaction, user):
    return str(reaction.emoji) in ['', ''] and user != bot.user

try:
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=3600.0, check=green_check)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await concept_msg.delete()
    await ctx.author.send("No moderator responded, wait some time and try again.")
    return
else:
    if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
        #do something
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == '':
        #do something else
    else:
        pass
```